# Probability of two stochastic variables being equal

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If we have two stochastic variables $X$ and $Y$, both having a binomial distribution of $Bin(1,1/2)$. With a correlation coefficient $\rho(X,Y) = 1/2$, what is $P(X=Y)$?

I have so far been looking into how to calculate $P(X-Y) = 0$, but am unfortunately quite stuck. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data $\rho\left(X,Y\right)=\frac{1}{2}$ enables you to find $\mathbb{E}XY=P\left(XY=1\right)=P\left(X=1\wedge Y=1\right)$
on base of:

$$\rho\left(X,Y\right)=\frac{\mathbb{E}XY-\mu_{X}\mu_{Y}}{\sigma_{X}\sigma_{Y}}$$

This on its turn enables you to find the probabilities $P\left(X=0\wedge Y=1\right)$,
$P\left(X=1\wedge Y=0\right)$ and $P\left(X=0\wedge Y=0\right)$

Finally: $$P\left(X=Y\right)=P\left(X=0\wedge Y=0\right)+P\left(X=1\wedge Y=1\right)$$